# Page not re-rendering on change? Method not working?

Tags: visualforce, rerender, apexactionfunction, onchange

I am trying to run a soql query based on an input value on a `Visualforce Page`.  However, I don't see that the results are displayed on the page when the input field is changed.

VF Page:

```
<apex:page StandardController="Loan_Memo__c" Extensions="ReviewAccountCovenants" >
    <apex:form >
        <div>
            <apex:pageBlock id="thePageBlock" mode="edit" >
                <apex:pageBlockButtons location="top" >
                <apex:commandButton value="Update Covenants" action="{!updatecovs}" />
                </apex:pageBlockButtons>  
                 <apex:actionRegion>
                    <apex:pageBlockSection > 
                        <apex:inputField value="{!Loan_Memo__c.Relationship__c}" />
                            <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" action="{!getrelatedcovs}" reRender="covenanttable" status="status" />
                    </apex:pageBlockSection>   
                </apex:actionRegion  >
                <apex:actionStatus startText="applying value..." id="status" />
                    <apex:pageBlockTable    var="covenant"
                                            value="{!relatedcovs}"
                                            id="covenanttable"
                                            >
                         <apex:column headerValue="Covenant Type">
                            <apex:outputText value="{!covenant.LLC_BI__Covenant_Type__r.Name}"  rendered="{!Loan_Memo__c.Relationship__c != null}"/>
                         </apex:column>
                        <apex:column headerValue="Requirement">
                            <apex:inputField value="{!covenant.Requirement__c}" />
                         </apex:column>      
                        <apex:column headerValue="Actual">
                            <apex:inputField value="{!covenant.Actual__c}" />
                        </apex:column>        
                </apex:pageBlockTable>
            </apex:pageBlock>
        </div>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You used a self closing input. You need to leave it open to nest the `actionSupport` under it.

**Incorrect**

```
<apex:inputField ... />
    <apex:actionSupport ... />
```

**Correct**

```
<apex:inputField ...>
    <apex:actionSupport ... />
</apex:inputField>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to include `actionsupport` inside your `inputfield`

```
<apex:inputField value="{!Loan_Memo__c.Relationship__c}" > 
  <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" action="{!getrelatedcovs}" reRender="covenanttable" status="status" /> 
</apex: inputfield>
```